# Full table scan on partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables (pageviews and base_events) that are both partitioned on a date field derived_tstamp. Every night I'm doing an incremental update to the base_events table, querying the new data from pageviews like so:

```
  select
    *
  from
    `project.sp.pageviews`
    where derived_tstamp > (select max(derived_tstamp) from `project.sp_modeled.base_events`)
```

Looking at the query costs, this query scans the full table instead of only the new data. Usually this should only get yesterdays data.

Do you have any idea, what's wrong with the query?

Comment: After more digging, I understand now, that pruning is not possible with subqueries.

The basic solution would be to use scripting: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare

Comment: Yeah, you found the right solution!

Comment: @Andii feel free to add an answer to your own question if you found one, that helps other people find it in future if they have the same question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subqueries will trigger a full table scan. The solution is to use scripting. I have solved my problem with the following query:

```
declare event_date_checkpoint DATE default (
      select max(date(page_view_start)) from `project.sp_modeled.base_events
  );

select
    *
  from
    `project.sp.pageviews`
    where derived_tstamp > event_date_checkpoint
```

More on scripting:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare